# Is there an efficient way to check if line collides with an object specified by n planes?

Tags: 3d, line, collision-detection, plane

I have a map which is made up of brushes/objects consisting of 6 or more planes.

I have to check if a given line/ray intersects with any of the given brushes/objects.

For example, a cuboid could be specified by the following 6 planes (each described by 3 vertices that are not in the same line):

```
(-128 32 128) (128 32 128) (128 0 128)
(-128 0 0) (128 0 0) (128 32 0)
(-128 32 128) (-128 0 128) (-128 0 0)
(128 32 0) (128 0 0) (128 0 128)
(128 32 128) (-128 32 128) (-128 32 0)
(128 0 0) (-128 0 0) (-128 0 128)
```

An illustration by Valve:
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/w/images/0/0d/Brush_planes.gif

Although Valve seems to use the same format in some of their tools, this project is not using the Source engine and I cannot use any already built frameworks to achieve this task.

I already have a working implementation of line-plane intersection so that I can see if a given line intersects with any of the planes of the object but I can't grasp how to efficiently check whether the line will actually collide with the object (if the line is not parallel with the planes, it will eventually intersect with all of them - this however doesn't tell me anything about the line hitting the actual object).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.